# Update arrays in json object

Tags: python, arrays, json

Tried to update the array in json object. Here is my json object

```
   {
    "api.version": "v1",
    "source": {
        "thirdPartyRef": {
            "resources": [{
                "serviceType": "AwsElbBucket",
                "path": {
                    "pathExpression": "songs/*"
                },
                "authentication": {
                    "type": "S3BucketAuthentication"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
  }
```

Code that reads json and update awsId. My requirement is to add aws creds int the authentication secition.

Once program run successfully, it should look like

```
       "authentication": {
          "type": "S3BucketAuthentication",
          "awsId": "AKIAXXXXX",
          "awsKey": "MYHSHSYjusXXX"
       }
```

Here is my snippet of code args[5] is the jsonfile

```
with open(args[5]) as json_data:
        source = json.loads(json_data.read())
#       source['source']['category']['awsID'] = "test"
source.update( {"awsId" : "AKIAXXXXX", "awsKey": "HHSJSHS"})
print source
```

output:

```
{u'api.version': u'v1', 'awsKey': 'HHSJSHS', 'awsId': 'AKIAXXXXX', u'source': {u'thirdPartyRef': {u'resources': [{u'path': {u'pathExpression': u'songs/*'}, u'serviceType': u'AwsElbBucket', u'authentication': {u'type': u'S3BucketAuthentication'}}]}}}
```

I tried to `source.update( "source":{"awsId" : "AKIAXXXXX", "awsKey": "HHSJSHS"}})`, it overwrites the rest of the json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data structure that you want to update is buried fairly deeply. You can't access it from the very top level.

Try this:

```
import json
with open('arg5.json') as json_data:
        source = json.loads(json_data.read())
print source
source["source"]["thirdPartyRef"]["resources"][0]["authentication"].update(
    {"awsId" : "AKIAXXXXX", "awsKey": "HHSJSHS"})
```